# convert object of type bytearray to JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm reading data from json documents stored as azure blob on datalake storage and covert them to type bytearray. Once I process all of this data I need to convert the data back as string so it can be json serializable. I'm using the below code to accomplish this. But, not sure how to convert the data back as string for json serializable.

***Code***

```
import json
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

account = "myAccount"
container = "myContainer"
blob_name = "myBlob.json"

default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account, credential=default_credential)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
data = bytearray(blob_client.download_blob().readall())

    batch_size = 1000

    process = json.loads(data)

    for batch in [process[i:i+batch_size] for i in range(0, len(process), batch_size)]:        
    # process data
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [[JSON]: Introducing JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), byte array is not among supported types. The closest thing would be a string, so you have to convert it (using its *decode* method):

> ```
> >>> import json
> >>>
> >>> ba = bytearray(b"{\"1\":2}")
> >>> ba
> bytearray(b'{"1":2}')
> >>> js = json.dumps(ba.decode())
> >>> js
> '"{\\"1\\":2}"'
> >>> s = json.loads(js)
> >>> s, type(s)
> ('{"1":2}', <class 'str'>)
> ```

But, if you're transferring data so in the other size you convert it back to byte array (the code suggests that your data is the input / output of an inference), *JSON* might not be the best choice (performance wise), so you might want to consider *Pickle*, or *Google*'s *ProtoBuf*.